# How to narrow data in a list

Tags: python

I am having an issue with a python script I am running that is attempting to get one of the 22 top trending topics on the PyTrends (https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/) from the output printed. I am trying to create a random number from 1 to 22, and then use that to choose one of the 22 results printed on lines 176-198 in the python shell.

```
import pytrends
import random


pytrend = TrendReq()
random = random.randint(1,22)
random = random + 99
itemList = list(pytrend.trending_searches())
Data = itemList.index(random) # This is one of the issue lines, as I cannot figure out how to index the output as needed.
Data = str(Data) 
Data = Data[1:21] # An attempt at indexing output
print (Data)
```

This is my output on the Shell:

```
    <bound method NDFrame.head of         date                                         exploreUrl  \
0   20180504  /trends/explore?q=Free+Comic+Book+Day&date=now...   
1   20180504  /trends/explore?q=Brad+Marchand&date=now+7-d&g...   
2   20180504  /trends/explore?q=jrue+holiday&date=now+7-d&ge...   
3   20180504  /trends/explore?q=Kentucky+Derby&date=now+7-d&...   
4   20180504  /trends/explore?q=Cinco+de+Mayo&date=now+7-d&g...   
5   20180504     /trends/explore?q=Warriors&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
6   20180504       /trends/explore?q=Bruins&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
7   20180504      /trends/explore?q=Rockets&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
8   20180504  /trends/explore?q=Matt+Harvey&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
9   20180504    /trends/explore?q=DJ+Khaled&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
10  20180504  /trends/explore?q=Matthew+Lawrence&date=now+7-...   
11  20180504   /trends/explore?q=junot+diaz&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
12  20180504  /trends/explore?q=nashville+predators&date=now...   
13  20180504  /trends/explore?q=albert+pujols&date=now+7-d&g...   
14  20180504  /trends/explore?q=indians+vs+yankees&date=now+...   
15  20180504  /trends/explore?q=zoe+saldana&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
16  20180504      /trends/explore?q=Rihanna&date=now+7-d&geo=US   
17  20180504  /trends/explore?q=Becky+Hammon&date=now+7-d&ge...   
18  20180504  /trends/explore?q=dte+outage+map&date=now+7-d&...   
19  20180504  /trends/explore?q=hawaii+news+now&date=now+7-d...   
20  20180504  /trends/explore?q=Colton+Haynes&date=now+7-d&g...   
21  20180504  /trends/explore?q=Audrey+Hepburn&date=now+7-d&...   
22  20180504  /trends/explore?q=Carol+Burnett&date=now+7-d&g...   

   formattedTraffic hotnessColor  hotnessLevel  \
0           20,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
1           20,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
2           20,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
3        2,000,000+      #d04108           5.0   
4        1,000,000+      #db601e           4.0   
5          500,000+      #db601e           4.0   
6          200,000+      #e68033           3.0   
7          200,000+      #e68033           3.0   
8          200,000+      #e68033           3.0   
9          200,000+      #e68033           3.0   
10         100,000+      #e68033           3.0   
11         100,000+      #e68033           3.0   
12         100,000+      #e68033           3.0   
13         100,000+      #e68033           3.0   
14         100,000+      #e68033           3.0   
15          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
16          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
17          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
18          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
19          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
20          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
21          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   
22          50,000+      #f0a049           2.0   

                                           imgLinkUrl              imgSource  \
0   https://wtop.com/entertainment/2018/05/grab-fr...                   WTOP   
1   http://www.espn.com/nhl/story/_/id/23414142/nh...                   ESPN   
2   https://www.slamonline.com/nba/jrue-holiday-an...            SLAM Online   
3   https://www.nbcnews.com/business/business-news...            NBCNews.com   
4   https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/05/business/ci...         New York Times   
5   https://www.goldenstateofmind.com/2018/5/5/173...   Golden State of Mind   
6   https://www.bostonglobe.com/sports/bruins/2018...       The Boston Globe   
7   http://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/23409022/ho...                   ESPN   
8   https://www.forbes.com/sites/tomvanriper/2018/...                 Forbes   
9   http://people.com/music/dj-khaled-2015-video-w...             PEOPLE.com   
10  https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/life/a2015507...   GoodHousekeeping.com   
11  https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-e...        Washington Post   
12  https://www.tennessean.com/story/sports/nhl/pr...         The Tennessean   
13  https://www.cbssports.com/mlb/news/leaderboard...          CBSSports.com   
14  https://www.mlb.com/news/miguel-andujar-yankee...                MLB.com   
15  http://people.com/movies/mila-kunis-gets-emoti...             PEOPLE.com   
16          http://www.bbc.com/news/newsbeat-44000486               BBC News   
17  http://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/23407719/be...                   ESPN   
18  https://www.lansingstatejournal.com/story/news...  Lansing State Journal   
19  http://www.hawaiinewsnow.com/story/38110613/li...        Hawaii News Now   
20  http://people.com/tv/colton-haynes-denies-rumo...             PEOPLE.com   
21  http://people.com/movies/see-audrey-hepburn-in...             PEOPLE.com   
22  https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/05/c...            Vanity Fair   

                                               imgUrl  \
0   //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgX9VkY3X0...   
1   //t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNtvvQkzuu...   
2   //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWuoUKvQM1...   
3   //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvx53B96Jy...   
4   //t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS7m8935VXh...   
5   //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQw4FYzAfaN...   
6   //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKEOxhee7r...   
7   //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMGOQfUc7u...   
8   //t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrbRgWqQM-...   
9   //t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTH2gEcxXtQ...   
10  //t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQuOq7biu30...   
11  //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQroHePQnEr...   
12  //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgdsziSLo-...   
13  //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8Z0CYLzOL...   
14  //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJUrmvZbvz...   
15  //t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSBQuX6A0c3...   
16  //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQU6AztveLs...   
17  //t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQX6uw7bDSG...   
18  //t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTKzcn18NOd...   
19  //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSizKTqReb...   
20  //t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjJAoEQ0A2...   
21  //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWzAeeA3c3...   
22  //t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCjUox_o9U...   

                                     newsArticlesList  \
0   [{'title': 'Grab a freebie on <b>Free Comic Bo...   
1   [{'title': 'NHL to give <b>Brad Marchand</b> e...   
2   [{'title': 'Pelicans&#39; <b>Jrue Holiday</b>:...   
3   [{'title': '<b>Kentucky Derby</b> Field: No. 5...   
4   [{'title': 'What Is <b>Cinco de Mayo</b>?', 'l...   
5   [{'title': '<b>Warriors</b> deservedly get the...   
6   [{'title': 'Dan Girardi lifts Lightning over <...   
7   [{'title': '<b>Rockets</b> take 2-1 lead by bl...   
8   [{'title': '<b>Matt Harvey</b> And Mets Just C...   
9   [{'title': '<b>DJ Khaled</b> Faces Critics Aft...   
10  [{'title': '<b>Matthew Lawrence</b> Proposed t...   
11  [{'title': 'Pulitzer Prize-winning author <b>J...   
12  [{'title': '<b>Predators</b> coach Peter Lavio...   
13  [{'title': 'Leaderboarding: The astounding Hal...   
14  [{'title': 'Andujar walks off Yanks to 13th wi...   
15  [{'title': 'Mila Kunis Gets Emotional at BFF <...   
16  [{'title': '<b>Rihanna</b> opens up about her ...   
17  [{'title': 'Sources: Spurs assistant <b>Becky ...   
18  [{'title': 'Crews restoring power quickly afte...   
19  [{'title': 'LIST: Lava threat forces evacuatio...   
20  [{'title': '<b>Colton Haynes</b> Shuts Down Ru...   
21  [{'title': 'See <b>Audrey Hepburn</b> in Gorge...   
22  [{'title': '<b>Carol Burnett</b> Wants to Be L...   

                                  relatedSearchesList  safe  \
0                                                  []   1.0   
1                                                  []   1.0   
2                                                  []   1.0   
3   [{'query': 'Kentucky Derby 2018 horses', 'safe...   1.0   
4   [{'query': 'Cinco De Mayo 2018 Events', 'safe'...   1.0   
5   [{'query': 'Warriors Vs Pelicans', 'safe': Tru...   1.0   
6   [{'query': 'Boston Bruins', 'safe': True}, {'q...   1.0   
7        [{'query': 'Rockets Vs Jazz', 'safe': True}]   1.0   
8                                                  []   1.0   
9         [{'query': 'Dj Khaled Wife', 'safe': True}]   1.0   
10          [{'query': 'Cheryl Burke', 'safe': True}]   1.0   
11                                                 []   1.0   
12             [{'query': 'Predators', 'safe': True}]   1.0   
13                                                 []   1.0   
14                                                 []   1.0   
15                                                 []   1.0   
16                                                 []   1.0   
17                                                 []   1.0   
18                                                 []   1.0   
19                                                 []   1.0   
20                                                 []   1.0   
21                                                 []   1.0   
22                                                 []   1.0   

                                             shareUrl     startTime  \
0   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Fr...  1.525540e+09   
1   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Br...  1.525543e+09   
2   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Jr...  1.525532e+09   
3   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ke...  1.525460e+09   
4   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ci...  1.525453e+09   
5   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Wa...  1.525482e+09   
6   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Br...  1.525486e+09   
7   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ro...  1.525493e+09   
8   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ma...  1.525468e+09   
9   https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=DJ...  1.525475e+09   
10  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ma...  1.525439e+09   
11  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ju...  1.525457e+09   
12  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Na...  1.525435e+09   
13  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Al...  1.525439e+09   
14  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=In...  1.525486e+09   
15  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Zo...  1.525446e+09   
16  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ri...  1.525432e+09   
17  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Be...  1.525493e+09   
18  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Dt...  1.525468e+09   
19  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ha...  1.525453e+09   
20  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Co...  1.525489e+09   
21  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Au...  1.525475e+09   
22  https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?stt=Ca...  1.525478e+09   

                  title                                   titleLinkUrl  \
0   Free Comic Book Day  //www.google.com/search?q=Free+Comic+Book+Day   
1         Brad Marchand        //www.google.com/search?q=Brad+Marchand   
2          Jrue Holiday         //www.google.com/search?q=Jrue+Holiday   
3        Kentucky Derby       //www.google.com/search?q=Kentucky+Derby   
4         Cinco de Mayo        //www.google.com/search?q=Cinco+de+Mayo   
5              Warriors             //www.google.com/search?q=Warriors   
6                Bruins               //www.google.com/search?q=Bruins   
7               Rockets              //www.google.com/search?q=Rockets   
8           Matt Harvey          //www.google.com/search?q=Matt+Harvey   
9             DJ Khaled            //www.google.com/search?q=DJ+Khaled   
10     Matthew Lawrence     //www.google.com/search?q=Matthew+Lawrence   
11           Junot Diaz           //www.google.com/search?q=Junot+Diaz   
12  Nashville Predators  //www.google.com/search?q=Nashville+Predators   
13        Albert Pujols        //www.google.com/search?q=Albert+Pujols   
14   Indians Vs Yankees   //www.google.com/search?q=Indians+Vs+Yankees   
15          Zoe Saldana          //www.google.com/search?q=Zoe+Saldana   
16              Rihanna              //www.google.com/search?q=Rihanna   
17         Becky Hammon         //www.google.com/search?q=Becky+Hammon   
18       Dte Outage Map       //www.google.com/search?q=Dte+Outage+Map   
19      Hawaii News Now      //www.google.com/search?q=Hawaii+News+Now   
20        Colton Haynes        //www.google.com/search?q=Colton+Haynes   
21       Audrey Hepburn       //www.google.com/search?q=Audrey+Hepburn   
22        Carol Burnett        //www.google.com/search?q=Carol+Burnett   

    trafficBucketLowerBound  
0                   20000.0  
1                   20000.0  
2                   20000.0  
3                 2000000.0  
4                 1000000.0  
5                  500000.0  
6                  200000.0  
7                  200000.0  
8                  200000.0  
9                  200000.0  
10                 100000.0  
11                 100000.0  
12                 100000.0  
13                 100000.0  
14                 100000.0  
15                  50000.0  
16                  50000.0  
17                  50000.0  
18                  50000.0  
19                  50000.0  
20                  50000.0  
21                  50000.0  
22                  50000.0  >
```

Comment: Looks like the output for a different command if you ask me...

Comment: Yes, I know. I think Pytrends outputs all of this with that little snippet, which is quite annoying. I just wanted one of the 22 most popular.

Comment: The output you're seeing is completely unrelated to your `print` call at the end. You will either get a number from `list.index`, or it will raise an exception. The rest of the manipulations you do to `Data` don't seem at all useful (you convert the number to a string, then slice some characters from it that it may not have). Were you looking to do `Data = imgList[random]`? Also it's probably a bad idea to use `random` as a variable, since that overwrites the name of the random module that you imported.

Comment: You are getting a pandas dataframe out of your request - take a look at the pandas package to figure out how to get what you want after the pytrend.trending_searches() step

Comment: @jeremycg I just looked at how to filter a pandas dataframe at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html, but it didn't fully explain how to filter the correct characters out in my situation.

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry I didn't explain, this was the output of pytrends without any of the filters applied.

Answer (score 0):

pytrends returns a pandas dataframe as an output. Pandas dataframes have all sorts of useful methods for subsetting and indexing, so when you call list and str on it rather than the native methods you are getting some weird results.

To take a random sample of a dataframe, you can use the [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method:

```
data.sample(n)
```

So, to get you a randomly chosen row from the request:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()

mydata = pytrend.trending_searches()
print(mydata.sample(1)) #or assign it, or get the required rows etc
```